# Users created by seeder can login, registered users not

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

My Laravel/Vue application has a UserSeeder, generating several admin users during the `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` command.

```
/**
 * Seed users table
 */
public function run()
{
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'firstname' => 'Admin',
        'lastname' => 'User',
        'email' => 'admin@user.com',
        'role' => 1,
        'password' => bcrypt('admin')
    ]);
}
```

Visitors are allowed to register through a Vue registration page. After submitting the registration, the user details are stored correctly into the database without any error using the following code:

```
/**
 * Register a new user
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'firstname' => 'required|min:3',
        'lastname' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'  => 'required|min:3|confirmed',
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'errors' => $v->errors()
        ], 422);
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->role = 2;
    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
}
```

After registering users should be able to login immediately (no further confirmation of activation of their account). Like the registration page, the login page is in Vue and after submitting the login form the users' email and password are used to authenticate the user, using the following code:

```
/**
 * Login user and return a token
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200)->header('Authorization', $token);
    } else {
         return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'errors' => [
                'combination' => 'combination'
            ]
        ], 422);
    }
    return response()->json(['error' => 'login_error'], 401);
}

/**
 * Return auth guard
 */
private function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}
```

The strange this is, the users created by the UserSeeder are able to login through the login form, but users that try to login after using the registration form receive the email/password combination error.

Comment: A `role`-thing maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

First I would check if the password typed in the frontend got to the controller.
`=> check $request->password`
You can also try `bcrypt('passwordUsedInFrontend')` in php artisan tinker console and check if that is the same to the one in your database.
Seems to be a debugging job.

Comment: Unfortunately the filled in email and password in the register and login methods are equal. 

Difference in the bcrypt outcome is exactly how bcrypt should work. e.g. bcrypt the string 'test' multiple times, results in different strings. So even if the hash values are different, the password matching won't fail.

Comment: You can check if the password is correct with Hash::check(requestPasswordPlain, hashFromDatabase), see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing. If the password is working fine, the only difference is the role, right?